# Post forms with coffescript/ ajax in play

Tags: ajax, forms, playframework, coffeescript

I try to submit a simple form with coffeescript/ajax in play. But I'm doing something wrong and can't figure out what.
I started with a working form for creating questions (without ajax) and then followed [Playframwork doc on javascript routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting):

So first I created the router resource in my Application controller:

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
      routes.javascript.Questions.create
    )
  ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

added in routes:

```
GET         /javascriptRoutes          controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

added to my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes()'></script>
```

and then included the coffescript:

```
$ ->
  $('#save').on "click", (e) ->
    jsRoutes.controllers.Questions.create.ajax
      data: $('#questionForm').serialize()
      success: (data) ->
        alert("success")
      error: (err) ->
        alert("error")
```

#save points to a link and the onclick event works for a simple alert. $('#questionForm').serialize() also seems to output the right data.

The script simply does nothing and I don't know how to debug it properly with the chrome javascript debugger as I don't know where to look. At least intellij
tells me that Questions.create is never called.

edit: Thanks to Infinity I noticed that the chrome javascript debugger throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jsRoutes.controllers.Questions.create.ajax is not a function(anonymous function) @ save.coffee:3m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4641m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4309
```

Comment: Check network tab to see if your browser sends requests to `Questions.create` route and if there are any errors in console tab

Comment: You're right in the console tab it says:

    Uncaught TypeError: jsRoutes.controllers.Questions.create.ajax is not a function(anonymous function) @ save.coffee:3m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4641m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Infinity and the new console error input I noticed that

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Questions.create.ajax
```

must be

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Questions.create().ajax
```